# C# -- Active Directory -- accountExpires property not reading correctly

Tags: c#, active-directory, passwords

I am working on a tool that lists a number of properties of an active directory user. Currently I can show expiration date by adding 90 days (typical policy) to the lastPasswordSet property. However, some accounts are setup to never expire.

I've done some research and figured out that if the property, when converted to a long integer, equals 9223372036854775807 than the password never expires (or so I'm told).

The problem I'm having is that EVERY account I lookup has 9223372036854775807 as the accountExpires value. I have the microsoft AD tool and can verify which accounts are actually set to never expire and which ones expire in 90 days. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
    public bool doesPWExpire(string userDN)
    {
        DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(userDN);
        //get account expires property
        LargeInteger passChanged = ent.Properties["accountExpires"].Value as LargeInteger;

        //convert to data type long
        long int64Value = (long)((uint)passChanged.LowPart | (((long)passChanged.HighPart) << 32));

        if (int64Value == 9223372036854775807)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting long.MaxValue, a good value for "never". Your code is inconsistent, you are reading the "accountExpires" property but assigning to a variable named "passChanged".  Which suggests that you actually want to read a password related property.  Like "maxPwdAge" and "PasswordLastChanged".  Accounts don't usually expire, passwords do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That makes a lot of sense. Do you know of any other way to determine if the "Password does not expire" check is set in AD?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?  Create an account with a password that doesn't expire, check what you get back when you read maxPwdAge.

Comment: For reading and setting 'Password never expires' look at the 'userAccountControl' attribute and ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD

Comment: ***Accounts don't usually expire, passwords do.***

Not correct. Expiration date can be set for both account and password, both can expire.

Comment: Do focus on the word "usually" please.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine `DateTime expiry = DateTime.FromFileTime((int)ent.Properties["accountExpires"].Value)` will do the trick for you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting an invalid cast exception with this code. I'll keep playing with it but let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: You might have to cast it to a string and call int.parse or try casting to a long. I don't have a test environment handy.